# asp.net reuse connection and command

Tags: asp.net, mysql, datareader

before this i create a new "MySqlConnection" and "MySqlCommand" for 2_1 and 2_2, but it will make my code very long and confuse, so  i decided to reuse these which i already declared for 1_1. I have done that as below:

```
MySqlConnection connSelect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmdSelect = connSelect.CreateCommand();

cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("username", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
cmdSelect.Parameters["username"].Value = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();

cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = @username";

connSelect.Open();

MySqlDataReader drSelect1_1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

if (drSelect1_1.Read())
{
    //1_1
    this.lbl1_1.Text = drSelect1_1["username"].ToString();

//2_1
if (drSelect1_1["direct1"].ToString() != null)
{
    this.lbl2_1.Text = drSelect1_1["direct1"].ToString();

    connSelect.Close();
    cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '" + this.lbl2_1.Text + "'";
    connSelect.Open();

    MySqlDataReader drSelect2_1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

if (drSelect2_1.Read())
{
//some code
}
}

//2_2
if (drSelect1_1["direct2"].ToString() != null)      //ERROR HERE
{
    this.lbl2_2.Text = drSelect1_1["direct2"].ToString();
}
}
```

there is a error: "No current query in data reader" at 2_2, where i did wrong here? please advice me thx :)

Comment: Upvoted for a clear and genuine question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i out of my idea already, i move back to my origin method. i will come back to this question if my time is allows to. so by now you guys can take it as a reference. If you have a better solution, please share it with us. :) much appreciate.
So, basically, my idea is to create every MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, and MySqlDataReader for every "IF" condition. here you go.

```
  MySqlConnection connSelect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
  MySqlCommand cmdSelect = connSelect.CreateCommand();

  cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("username", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
  cmdSelect.Parameters["username"].Value = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();

  cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = @username";

  connSelect.Open();

  MySqlDataReader drSelect1_1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

  if (drSelect1_1.Read())
  {
      //1_1
      this.lbl1_1.Text = drSelect1_1["username"].ToString();   

      //2_1
      if (drSelect1_1["direct1"].ToString() != null)
      {
          this.lbl2_1.Text = drSelect1_1["direct1"].ToString();
          MySqlConnection connSelect2_1 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
          MySqlCommand cmdSelect2_1 = connSelect2_1.CreateCommand();

          cmdSelect2_1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '" + this.lbl2_1.Text + "'";

          connSelect2_1.Open();

          MySqlDataReader drSelect2_1 = cmdSelect2_1.ExecuteReader();

          if (drSelect2_1.Read())
          {
              //some code
          }
          connSelect2_1.Close();
      }

      //2_2
      if (drSelect1_1["direct2"].ToString() != null)
      {
          this.lbl2_2.Text = drSelect1_1["direct2"].ToString();

          MySqlConnection connSelect2_2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
          MySqlCommand cmdSelect2_2 = connSelect2_2.CreateCommand();

          cmdSelect2_2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '" + this.lbl2_2.Text + "'";

          connSelect2_2.Open();

          MySqlDataReader drSelect2_2 = cmdSelect2_2.ExecuteReader();

          if (drSelect2_2.Read())
          {
              //some code
          }
          connSelect2_2.Close();          
      }
  }
  connSelect.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should execute your 'if' conditions by iterating through the reader like this

```
while(drSelect1_1.read())
{

// IF CONDITIONS

}
```

This way you will not come across any null row

Comment: IF or WHILE doesn't make any different here. the code is back to functioning if i put 2_2 on the top of 2_1. i believe there must be something wrong at `connSelect.Close();` and `connSelect.Open();` under 2_1

Comment: you are right, you should not close the connection when iterating through it. Anyway, i suggested the while loop so that it gets iterated under only one open connection. Don't take me wrong. Thanks

Comment: @melvintcs - From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.71).aspx) Note that while a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use exclusively by that DataReader. You will not be able to execute any commands for the Connection, including creating another DataReader, until the original DataReader is closed.